# Java Lambda: how to use Stream.reduce to accomplish this?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a file of records, each row begins with a timestamp and then a few fields.. it implements Iterable

```Java
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public <E extends MarkedPoint>
         Stream<E>
         stream()
  {
    return (Stream<E>) StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);

  }
```

I would like to implement with Lambda expression/streams API what is essentially not just a filter, but a mapping/accumulator that would merge neighboring records ( stream elements  coming from the an Iterable interface ) having the same timestamp. I would need an interface that was something like this

```Java
MarkedPoint prevPoint = null;

void nextPoint(MarkedPoint in, Stream<MarkedPoint> inputStream, Stream<MarkedPoint> outputStream )
{
     while ( prevPoint.time == in.time )
     {
       updatePrevPoint(in);
       in = stream.next();
     }     
     outputStream.emit(in);
     prevPoint = in;
 } 
}
```

that is rough-pseudocode of what I imagine is close to some API as how it is supposed to be used.. can someone please point me towards the most straightforward way of implementing this stream transformation ?  The resulting stream will be necessarily of the same or lesser number of elements as the input, as it is essentially a filter and and option transformation of records occuring at the same timestamp are encountered.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use the built in? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: No luck with the standard Stream API. You may try StreamEx instead. But let’s talk about your broken `stream()` method first. The compiler warning you are suppressing is telling you something: you promise to return a stream of whatever subclass the caller wishes. I doubt that you can hold that promise. E.g., the caller can write `Stream<ChronoLocalDate> s = yourClass.stream();`. You don’t have a class extending `MarkedPoint` and implementing `ChronoLocalDate`? Not the caller’s problem. You promised to deliver it. The caller’s code will compile without any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Streams don’t work like that; there can be only 1 terminating method (consumer). What you seem to be asking for is an on-the-fly reduction with a possible consumption of the next element(s) within your class. No dice with the standard stream API.

You could first create a list of un-merged lines, then create an iterator that peeks at the next elenent(s) and merges them before returning the next merged element.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing